# How to scan doubles from a text file into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file that looks like this:

> Apple
>
> 10.1 20 11 21.3 31 12.7 22 32.4 42 13

The first line is the company name, the second line represents it's stock prices.

I want to scan in all the doubles into an array so that I can perform calculations.

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select A File");
    String FileName = keyboard.next();
 
    Scanner linReader = new Scanner(new File(FileName));
 
    double[] values = new double[10];
 
    while (linReader.hasNextLine()) {
        linReader.nextLine(); // skips company name
        String line = linReader.nextLine();
 
        // store following doubles into array
        int nums = 0; //
 
        if (linReader.hasNextDouble()) {
            values[nums] = linReader.nextDouble();
            nums++;
        }
 
    }
    linReader.close();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values)); //prints out array 'values'
}
```

I select the file, then I skip the first line (which contains the company name).

Then I initialize a number to keep track of the indeces in the array. If the line has another double, then it will be added to the array at the index 'num' and 'num' will increase by 1, this should continue until there are no more doubles.

At least that's the logic behind it. however the output always comes out to

> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

I am not sure why this happens or how to fix it.

Comment: `line` has all the values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `linReader.nextDouble()` is looking for a double *after* the previously read line.

Try to remove one call to `nextLine()`. If this doesn't help, use this algorithm:

```
linReader.nextLine(); // skips company name
String line = linReader.nextLine();
String[] strings = line.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    try {
        values[nums++] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Darn, had the same exact answer I was writing :)

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

The reason is because you are not utilizing the double line, and then the double array has default values, which are 0.0. The line:

```
String line = linReader.nextLine();
```

is part of the problem. When you do the following lines:

```
linReader.nextLine(); // skips company name
String line = linReader.nextLine();
```

The first line (`lineReader.nextLine`) where you hope to skip the company line, it reads `Apple`. That's all fine, but when you do,

```
String line = linReader.nextLine();
```

This will read the line of doubles. Then, your `if` is never executed because there are no more things to be read in the file, thus the double array's values are not assigned something other than the default values. Printing `line` you will see:

```
10.1 20 11 21.3 31 12.7 22 32.4 42 13
```

You can then do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.split(" ").length; i++) {
    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[i]);
}
```

Instead of the `if` statement. It will then correctly output:

```
[10.1, 20.0, 11.0, 21.3, 31.0, 12.7, 22.0, 32.4, 42.0, 13.0]
```

The code above does a traditional C-style for loop. It loops through the array of doubles, created by doing `line.split(" ")`, which splits all values at the space into an array. That creates:

```
["10.1", "20", "11, "21.3", "31", "12.7", "22", "32.4", "42", "13"]
```

Next, you just loop through all, access the `values` array with the current iteration or index, and assign it to a parsed double of the current element in the above string array. You can format, and catch any exceptions as needed.

---

## TL;DR

Here's the final code in the while-loop:

```
String companyName = linReader.nextLine(); // if you want the company name, this stores it
String line = linReader.nextLine(); // this contains all double values in a string
    
for(int i = 0; i < line.split(" ").length; i++) { // loops over all doubles in split string array
    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[i]); // parses them as doubles and then stores to double array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your code like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select A File");
    String FileName = keyboard.next();

    Scanner linReader = new Scanner(new File(FileName));

    Vector<Double> values = new Vector<>();

    while (linReader.hasNextLine()) {
        linReader.nextLine(); // skips company name
        String line = linReader.nextLine();
        String _line[] = line.split(" ");

        for (String item : _line) {
            if (!item.isEmpty()) {
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(item));
            }
        }
    }
    linReader.close();
    System.out.println(values.toString()); //prints out array 'values'
}
```